How to download an Excel file from ClosedXML in ASP.NET
I'm working on an ASP.NET webforms app, and I want to generate Excel files using ClosedXML from data that I retrieve from a database. So far, I've tried the example which should save the file to the C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\ folder, but it is throwing an UnauthorizedAccessException exception. The code that I use to (try) to download the file is from the package documentation, but workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream); throws the exception.
// Create the workbook
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample").Cell(1, 1).SetValue("Hello World");

// Prepare the response
HttpResponse httpResponse = Response;
httpResponse.Clear();
httpResponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
httpResponse.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"HelloWorld.xlsx\"");

// Flush the workbook to the Response.OutputStream
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
  memoryStream.WriteTo(httpResponse.OutputStream);
  memoryStream.Close();
}

httpResponse.End();

I just want to download the generated file to the user's Downloads folder. Actually there are some other methods that download files on the same app that I'm working on, but they retrieve them from a database and send the blob data to the output stream, so it is not as in this example.

After asking a colleague, I found the solution: it turns out that the button was inside an UpdatePanel, but I didn't specify the complete postback on the trigger. I just needed to add the following lines, and now the download works like a charm:
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDownloadExcelReport" />
</Triggers>


In general, a postback trigger is only required for a button if it is outside of the update panel.  Also, for using transmit file, or writing to the current http output, then often a update panel will not work anyway.
